# Cant connect to orange m2m using soap

Tags: php, soap, wsdl, m2m

I am trying to create a *`soap connection`* using the standard *`php soap client`* and I believe it is all correctly coded, however I am receiving this error :

```
 Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [WSDL] SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'https://m2mconnect.orange.co.uk/orange-soap/services/MessageServiceByCountry?wsdl' : Start tag expected, '<' not found in C:\wamp\www\php\run.php:16 Stack trace: #0 C:\wamp\www\php\run.php(16): SoapClient->SoapClient('https://m2mconn...') #1 {main} thrown in C:\wamp\www\php\run.php on line 16
```

From what I have found online it seems one problem may be to do with the ports, however im not sure which ports to check/use or how to.

Im also unsure if it is something to do with my internet connection as it is a little strange being from one router to another.

Here is my code:

```
$client = new SoapClient("https://m2mconnect.orange.co.uk/orange-soap/services/MessageServiceByCountry?wsdl");
```

Comment: It says a start tag was expected in  `MessageServiceByCountry?wsdl` , would you post the wsdl file you're using?

Comment: the link : https://m2mconnect.orange.co.uk/orange-soap/services/MessageServiceByCountry?wsdl is to the wsdl file its an online file is this correct to pass the web address ?

Comment: wow, possibly a problem with your php instalation, check this ...
https://m2mconnect.orange.co.uk/orange-soap/services/MessageServiceByCountry?wsdl

Comment: I am using a standard wamp install which I reinstalled because of issues a day ago. I have turned on the extensions for soap and openssl too. I asked a friend to run it and he had the same errors so i dont believe it to be my internet. Would it be better to download the xml file at the web address and use it that way ?

Comment: I just checked the same soapclient call with no problems at all. (Testing with WAMP also). Check the [soap] info in php.ini (the `C:\wamp\bin\apache\Apachexx\bin\php.ini` file)

Comment: It says that soap is enabled I used the wamp menu system to turn it on

[soap]
; Enables or disables WSDL caching feature.
; http://php.net/soap.wsdl-cache-enabled
soap.wsdl_cache_enabled=1

; Sets the directory name where SOAP extension will put cache files.
; http://php.net/soap.wsdl-cache-dir
soap.wsdl_cache_dir="/tmp"

; (time to live) Sets the number of second while cached file will be used 
; instead of original one.
; http://php.net/soap.wsdl-cache-ttl
soap.wsdl_cache_ttl=86400

; Sets the size of the cache limit. (Max. number of WSDL files to cache)
soap.wsdl_cache_limit = 5